# PostgreSQL select daily max and corresponding hour of ocurrence

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table structure, with daily-hourly data:

```
time_of_ocurrence(timestamp); particles(numeric)

"2012-11-01 00:30:00";191.3
"2012-11-01 01:30:00";46
 ...
"2013-01-01 02:30:00";319.6
```

How do i select the **DAILY max and THE HOUR in which this max occur**?
I've tried

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', time_of_ocurrence) as hora,
MAX(particles)
from my_table WHERE time_of_ocurrence > '2013-09-01'
GROUP BY hora ORDER BY hora
```

But it doesn't work:

```
"2013-09-01 00:00:00";34.35
"2013-09-01 01:00:00";33.13
"2013-09-01 02:00:00";33.09
"2013-09-01 03:00:00";28.08
```

My result would be in this format instead (one max per day, showing the hour)

```
"2013-09-01 05:00:00";100.35
"2013-09-02 03:30:00";80.13
```

How can i do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of question has come up on StackOverflow frequently, and these questions are categorized with the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag, if you want to see other solutions.

*edit:* I changed the following code to group by day instead of by hour.

Here's one solution:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT date_trunc('day', time_of_ocurrence) as hora, MAX(particles) AS particles
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY hora
) AS _max
INNER JOIN my_table AS t 
  ON _max.hora = date_trunc('day', t.time_of_ocurrence)
  AND _max.particles = t.particles
WHERE time_of_ocurrence > '2013-09-01'
ORDER BY time_of_ocurrence;
```

This might also show more than one result per day, if more than one row has the max value.

Another solution using window functions that does not show such duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', time_of_ocurrence) 
        ORDER BY particles DESC) AS _rn
  FROM my_table
) AS _max
WHERE _rn = 1
ORDER BY time_of_ocurrence;
```

If multiple rows have the same max, one row with nevertheless be numbered row 1.  If you need specific control over which row is numbered 1, you need to use ORDER BY in the partitioning clause using a unique column to break such ties.

Comment: it still showing values from the same day. I'm trying to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select distinct
  date_trunc('day',time_of_ocurrence) as day,
  max(particles) over (partition by date_trunc('day',time_of_ocurrence)) as particles_max_of_day,
  first_value(date_trunc('hour',time_of_ocurrence)) over (partition by date_trunc('day',time_of_ocurrence) order by particles desc)
from my_table
order by 1
```

One edge case here is if the same MAX number of particles show up in the same day, but in different hours. This version would randomly pick one of them. If you prefer one over the other (always the earlier one for example) you can add that to the order by clause:

```
      first_value(date_trunc('hour',time_of_ocurrence)) over (partition by date_trunc('day',time_of_ocurrence) order by particles desc, time_of_ocurrence)
```

Comment: This is showing more than one result per day, my goal is the max value for the day, and the hour of occurrence. But i think you're close!

Comment: @Fernando edited again after having access to a db.. but it works now! :)

Comment: Thanks, it works! it truncates the hour tough (for 08:30:00 i get 08:00:00), for example.